# ZFS mismatched replication level

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a RAIDZ1 running 6x 3TB drives, and I want to expand my pool by adding 5x 2TB drives to it. But when I tell it to add to the pool I get this:

```
$ zpool add zpool1 raidz1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
mismatched replication level: pool uses 6-way raidz and new vdev uses 5-way raidz
```

Just how bad is doing this? I don't care about performance, this server does not need massive performance, it needs storage. Will this damage my data to do this or is it fine to expand to different size pools like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While having RAIDZ vdevs of different width is not recommended, it is a valid configuration to use. The key point is to use the *same* redundancy level - RAIDZ1 in this case.

In other words - the ZFS warning is a valid one, but using `-f` can be justified in this specific case. You should obviously be mindful of what it means, as both performance and space efficiency (ie: via un-optimal padding) will be affected.

Anyway, data will not be damaged and redundancy will not be lowered by adding another RAIDZ1 vdev.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea. Is there a good reason you won't use appropriately sized drives?

Even in the realm of used disks, 3TB drives are very inexpensive, so I hope cost isn't the concern.

Comment: But why?? Its not complaining about drive sizes, if you read the error its complaining about 6 drives vs 5 drives in the vdev.

Comment: Yes, that's a bad idea as well.

Comment: The question already suggests its a bad idea.. but *how* bad; with what effect? -- Is it going to use extra cycles and space to make it work? Or will it leave significant disk space unused? Does it degrade the reliability, or even produce incorrect output when later asking what the resulting pool is going to behave like?

Comment: No idea. It’s not our job to talk people out of bad ideas.

Comment: Looking through the lens of a professional systems engineer, this is just creating technical debt for the next person that touches this system. The cost of doing it correctly is *so* low that it makes entertaining the “bad idea” unreasonable.